# Get difference from top ranked item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the following query to rank items, but I need it to also show the difference between the item and the top ranked item (The top ranked item will show the difference between it and the 2nd ranked item.), like so:

```
SELECT rdate, rtime, SF, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY rdate, rtime ORDER BY rdate, 
rtime, SF DESC) rank
FROM DailySF

rdate      |  rtime  |  SF  | rank  | DiffTop
-------------------------------------------
18/02/2021    09:00     54     1        2
18/02/2021    09:00     52     2       -2
18/02/2021    09:00     50     3       -4
19/02/2021    09:00     53     1       10
19/02/2021    09:00     43     2      -10
19/02/2021    09:00     40     3      -13
19/02/2021    09:00     35     4      -18
```

How do I create the DiffTop column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions for this as well:

```
SELECT rdate, rtime, SF,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY rdate, rtime ORDER BY rdate, 
rtime, SF DESC) as rank,
       (SF - MAX(SF) OVER (PARTITION BY rdate, rtime)) as diff
FROM DailySF;
```

The top ranked value is the one with maximum `SF`.

To handle the top ranked item:

```
SELECT rdate, rtime, SF,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY rdate, rtime ORDER BY rdate, 
rtime, SF DESC) as rank,
       (CASE WHEN SF = MAX(SF) OVER (PARTITION BY rdate, rtime)
             THEN SF - LEAD(SF) OVER (PARTITION BY rdate, rtime ORDER BY rtime)
             ELSE SF - MAX(SF) OVER (PARTITION BY rdate, rtime)
        END) as diff
FROM DailySF;
```

Comment: Thanks, but the top ranked value should be the difference between it and the 2nd ranked value, with this solution the 1st ranked diff is alway 0.

Comment: @user2096512 . . . That seems so undesirable, I missed that part of the question.  I modified the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it from LAG to LEAD as it was returning NULL, it now works as expected.